# How to reset form fields on select option change

Tags: angularjs

I am showing different input fields on form select options. But input validation applied for both select option input fields on form submit. Eg: if I select Online option and click on submit, its also validating miles input which is not visible. Here sharing code. Could you help me on what might be wrong.

```
<form class="form" name="form" role="form" ng-submit="locationsData()" novalidate>
        <div ng-repeat="address in locationsAddress.address">
            <select name="locationType" id="locationType" ng-model="locationsAddress.address[$index].type" ng-init="locationsAddress.address[$index].type = 'ONLINE'" class="form-control">
                <option value="ONLINE">Online</option>
                <option value="WORKER">Worker Address</option>
            </select>
            <div ng-if="locationsAddress.address[$index].type == 'WORKER'">
                <div style="margin: 20px 0;">
                    <label for="miles">miles you drive?</label>
                    <input type="text" name="distance{{address.id}}" id="distance" placeholder="miles you can drive?" ng-model="locationsAddress.address[$index].distance" required/>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.distance{{address.id}}.$touched">
                    <span class="error" ng-show="form.distance{{address.id}}.$error.required">Miles you drive is required.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="locationsAddress.address[$index].type == 'ONLINE'">
                <select name="chatType{{address.id}}" ng-model="locationsAddress.address[$index].appName" required>
                    <option value="" selected="selected">App Type</option>
                    <option value="SKYPE">Skype</option>
                    <option value="WHATSAPP">WhatsAPP</option>
                </select>
                <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.chatType{{address.id}}.$touched">
                    <span class="error" ng-show="form.chatType{{address.id}}.$error.required">Chat required.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Angular code:

```
$scope.locationsAddress = {

};
$scope.locationsAddress.address = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'type': '',
            'distance' : '',
            'appName': ''
        }
    ];
});
```

Whether reset form fields on select options helps? if yes, please share reference.

Comment: 1 - can you share a working snippet?
2 - what does locationsData() do?

Comment: @meno: locationsData() makes service call to submit user entered data. here sharing plunker link. but I am not sure how to handle service logic in plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/UdcdfGeiHpSPt5h8fMpg?p=preview.

Comment: the plnkr you provided had errors and uses different code.This is an error free version http://plnkr.co/edit/cQpTZHI6WARjaTyb5RUy?p=preview. When you say it is "validating miles input which is not visible" do you mean that the error message is shown? in the plnkr it isn't however.

Comment: @meno : error message shown for "miles....input field". I am new to angular. I didn't find how I can replicate local app form errors on plunker. So shared minimized code what I have in my local app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code needed refactoring. You shouldn't be using jQuery when you can use angular to manipulate you model:

```
 $scope.addAddress = function() {
    var id = 0;
    if ($scope.locationsAddress.address.length > 0) {
      id = $scope.locationsAddress.address[$scope.locationsAddress.address.length - 1].id + 1;
    } else {
      id = 1;
    }
    $scope.locationsAddress.address.push({
      id: id,
      type: 'PUBLIC'
    });
  };

 $scope.reset = function(index) {
   $scope.locationsAddress.address[index] = {
     id: $scope.locationsAddress.address[index].id,
     type: $scope.locationsAddress.address[index].type,
     appHandle: $scope.locationsAddress.address[index].appHandle
   };
   $scope.form.$setPristine();
 }
```

complete code: http://plnkr.co/edit/M6PzyV?p=info

I recommend you follow Angular Best Practices like [John Papa's](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: thanks for sharing simple and cleaner example. It works great except resetting the input fields to default state once form submit and toggle other select options. example: skip entering zip, city, state... ---> click submit button ----> we can see error messages (zip code required) ---> select "online" option ---> the form inputs should reset instead of showing error message for online select & user Id inputs. Here sharing plunker link where we can reproduce the issue. Could you help me to check and share inputs to resolve this issue. - http://plnkr.co/edit/jOFfqhhIjCvFHNNc29W5?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Use ng-form to separate forms when it comes under ng-repeat.

```
<form class="form" name="form" role="form" ng-submit="locationsData()" novalidate>
    <div ng-repeat="address in locationsAddress.address">
        <ng-form name="locationForm">
        <select name="locationType" id="locationType" ng-model="address.type" ng-init="address.type = 'ONLINE'" class="form-control" ng-change="form.$setPristine();">
            <option value="ONLINE">Online</option>
            <option value="WORKER">Worker Address</option>
        </select>
        <div ng-if="address.type == 'WORKER'">
            <div style="margin: 20px 0;">
                <label for="miles">miles you drive?</label>
                <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" placeholder="miles you can drive?" ng-model="address.distance" required/>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="form.$submitted || locationForm.distance.$touched">
                <span class="error" ng-show="locationForm.distance.$error.required">Miles you drive is required.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="address.type == 'ONLINE'">
            <select name="appName" ng-model="locationsAddress.address[$index].appName" required>
                <option value="" selected="selected">App Type</option>
                <option value="SKYPE">Skype</option>
                <option value="WHATSAPP">WhatsAPP</option>
            </select>
            <div ng-show="form.$submitted || locationForm.appName.$touched">
                <span class="error" ng-show="locationForm.appName.$error.required">Chat required.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ng-form>    
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/udwaxKohZl96GQoyFWgR

Comment: Which form will be taken if you submit common submit button?

Comment: All the changes(submitted values) will be available in corresponding scope /model variable when you submit from common submit button.

Comment: So your code will work if the OP put the button in inside of the ng-rpeat form

Comment: @PaulsonPeter: thanks for looking and sharing live example. As I requested, we should skip validating hidden input fields on form submit. We see "Miles you drive is required." error message for "Worker" option input fields though its not visible. Could you help me how we can prevent validating hidden inputs fields on form submit?

Comment: @Nikki Miles you drive will be visible when you select worker option so it becomes required. As per your code,(and as explained in your question) app type is the field which get hidden when you select 'Worker option'. Do you want the reverse of this?

Comment: @PaulsonPeter : I need to show "miles you drive" input field when we select "worker address" option. But "miles you drive" input filed should reset instead of showing error(Miles you drive is required.) it was not visible on form submit.

Comment: @Nikki I have added ng-change="form.$setPristine();" to reset the form for the select box. I think this is what you looking for. Check plunker.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this `locationsAddress.address[$index].type == 'ONLINE'` condition in your `ng-show` in where you display the error message

```
<div ng-show="(form.$submitted || form.distance{{address.id}}.$touched) && locationsAddress.address[$index].type == 'WORKER'">
                    <span class="error" ng-show="form.distance{{address.id}}.$error.required">Miles you drive is required.</span>
                </div>


<div ng-show="(form.$submitted || form.chatType{{address.id}}.$touched) &&  locationsAddress.address[$index].type == 'ONLINE'">
                    <span class="error" ng-show="form.chatType{{address.id}}.$error.required">Chat required.</span>
                </div>
```

Comment: experiencing same issue though I made recommended changes. Any other options please?